# Googles' QR code Generating api is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-api-client

I have been using chart API for a long time but from today onward it is not working any idea what is wrong with the Google API?

This is the API for generating QR code.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=230x230&chof=gif&&chl=100IP020180086500010001&choe=UTF-8&

Comment: Not working is a rather broad term. Why don't you check your browser console and logs for erros and edit your question? Right after reading the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is now depreciated and will no longer work.

Comment: Had the same problem this morning and found that the API is depreciated by google.  Ended up using http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/, which is essentially the library to generate a QR code without having to rely on 3rd party APIs.